# Checking if points fall within polygon Shapefile from Longhurst provinces

Tags: polygon, shapefile

I am trying to find the name of the corresponding Longhurst Province for several points of my dataset. I made a code but it gives me some errors so, something is not right... For example a point that I know is located in the Mediterranean Sea, the code return is APLR region (Austral Polar). Someone can help me with this? Thanks!

```
coord<-read.csv("~/Desktop/coord.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(coord)
names(coord) 

coord
station longitude latitude
1         1    -60.22   -62.40
2         2    -60.22   -62.40
3         3    -60.22   -62.40
4         4    -60.22   -62.40
5         5    -16.05    39.95
6         6    -16.05    39.95
7         7    -16.05    39.95
8         8    -16.05    39.95
9         9    -16.05    39.95
10       10    -18.72    35.87

Prov<-rep(NA,length(coord$station))

for (k in 1:length(coord$station))
{

  for (j in 1:length(Longhurst$dbf$dbf$ProvCode))
  {
sd<-rep(NA,54)
for ( i in seq(along=Longhurst$shp$shp[[j]]$parts))
{
  Puntos<-Longhurst$shp$shp[[j]]$points
  Partes<-Longhurst$shp$shp[[j]]$parts
  Partes<-c(Partes,nrow(Puntos))
  Poligono<-Puntos[(Partes[i]+1):(Partes[i+1]),]
  #lines(Poligono)
  InPoly<-which(point.in.polygon(coord$longitude[k],coord$latitude[k],Poligono$X,Poligono$Y)%in%c(1,2))
  Area[InPoly]<-as.character(Longhurst$dbf$dbf$ProvCode[j])
  sd[j]<-Area[1]
}
  }
  Prov[k]<-as.character(sd[54])
}
```